# Servlet with JSP and BNDtools

Tags: osgi, bndtools

I saw a good tutorial on Servlets with BNDtool here: http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/osgi_server/.

But how could I access static html-documents and JSPs from this Servlet? Where should I store them when I'd like to get them with `request.getRequestDispatcher("*.jsp")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a deeper look to [HttpService#registerResource](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/http/HttpService.html#registerResources%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.osgi.service.http.HttpContext%29). An appropriate implementation comes with [Apache Felix HttpService](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-http-service.html). That should solve your problem in a programmatically way. Unfortunality, I don't now any declarativ one.

**UPDATE**: Listing 7 on [this page](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-osgi3.html?page=2) gives you an overview how to use it. The rest of this article is used with the Equinox framework.